# Stack Overflow stats

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, statistics

I thought it would be cool (not going to use it for anything other than just "trivia") to know some stats about Stack Overflow such as:

1. The percentage of the questions asked that are duplicates of others.
2. The number of new users every day.
3. The number of users who have asked questions but not answered yet.
4. The number of users who have answered questions but not asked any yet.

Is there some page where I can find this information?

Comment: You can generate queries for much of this yourself using http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries

Comment: Oh I never knew about that. I would accept if you post that as an answer (with a brief description if not much of a bother) :)

Comment: A simple "Yes this is off-topic" would have sufficed to make me delete the question :) Oh well, loss of rep :(

Comment: @Sai The question has 1 upvote and 1 downvote. That's +5 -2 = +3 rep. In addition, you've also accepted an answer, so that's another +2 rep. In total, you've received +5 reputation from asking this question. Does that help with relieving the pain?

Comment: @RobW Yeah to a certain extent, but still my slate (of questions) was clean until now so that's disappointing. :)

Comment: This question seems to be *seeking input* on how to extract certain data about Stack Overflow, so how is this "Does not appear to seek input and discussion?"

Comment: @doubleDown I just took it as "it is more about info about SO itself rather than info about a feature/bug/discussion in SO" thus making it off-topic. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) to view some custom queries and even create ones of your own. I'm not sure if the specific queries you're looking for exist but it should be possible to create them if you know sql.

Comment: I will check :) I'm decent at SQL but not the best.