# Cannot delete off-topic question with an answer

Tags: support, off-topic

My [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187055/stats-about-stackoverflow) was deemed off-topic by several users and I probably agree with them. I would like it removed since it would be of use to no one on SO/MSO.

But the question was answered graciously and I accepted an answer before it was deemed off-topic, hence I cannot delete it now. Can I flag it for moderator deletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing, just leave it.  There's no reason for it to go away.  Deletion is for content that would be actively harmful to leave around, which doesn't seem to apply here.

It may be deleted automatically after some set period of time if it meets conditions that indicate it's not valuable (a low score, not being viewed, etc.)

Comment: Oh Ok that makes sense. Thanks.